# Как сделать кнопки счета количество товара (+ или -) в телеграмм бот python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как сделать кнопки счета(+ или -) в телеграмм бот python?
Сделал в телеграмм боте корзину и перед добавление в корзину пользователь должен выбрать количество товара с помощью кнопок + или -. Пример можете посмотреть на фото.
код ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if call.data == 'dobavit_v_korzinu':
    korzina_auto = a + 1
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    plus = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" ➕", callback_data='plus_one')
    summa = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f"{korzina_auto}", callback_data='summa')
    minus = types.InlineKeyboardButton("➖", callback_data='minus')

    dobavit_v_korzinu = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Добавить в корзину", 
    callback_data='dobavit_v_korzinu')

    exit_russian = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Назад", callback_data='exit')

    markup.add(minus, summa, plus, dobavit_v_korzinu, exit_russian)
    bot.edit_message_text(f'Минимальная партия составляет 10 шт.',
    call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, 
    reply_markup=markup)

elif call.data == 'plus_one':
    korzina_auto = a + 1
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    plus = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" ➕", callback_data='dobavit_v_korzinu')
    summa = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f"{korzina_auto}", callback_data='summa')
    minus = types.InlineKeyboardButton("➖", callback_data='minus')

    dobavit_v_korzinu = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Добавить в корзину", 
    callback_data='dobavit_v_korzinu')

    exit_russian = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Назад", callback_data='exit')

    markup.add(minus, summa, plus, dobavit_v_korzinu, exit_russian)
    bot.edit_message_text(f'Минимальная партия составляет 10 шт.',
    call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, 
    reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Весь код выложите, а не огрызками. Непонятно, где Вы с БД работаете

Comment: Какую библиотеку вы используете? aiogram? PyTelegramBotAPI?

Comment: Zhymabek Roman
 Я использую библиотеку telebot(PyTelegramBotApi)

Comment: напиши полный код, дай обратную связь